# SetPreference command not working in Selenium 3.0.0 with Firefox 48.0.1

Tags: selenium, firefox

I want to set the Firefox browser on any other page than the startup one. So i searched the internet and found this code:

```
FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();
    prof.SetPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
    prof.SetPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional",  "about:blank");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
```

The problem is that the SetPreference commands are returning:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
      QualifiedName
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    - Syntax error on token ",", < expected
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
 MethodHeaderName
```

Why is this happening? How can i make my code to work?

Thanks,
Tudor

Answer (score 0):

You mixed `C#` and `Java`. Methods in `Java` starts with small letters

```
prof.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
```

> Edit

Create class for the driver and initialize it there

```
public class MyDriver {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public MyDriver() {
        // initialize the driver
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Now you can access it from other classes

```
MyDriver driver = new MyDriver();
driver.getDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks Guy! One error down, 3 more to go:
`Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ",", < expected
 - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token ";", @ expected`

Comment: @Tudor all `SetPreference` should be `setPreference`

Comment: Did it, still 3 errors here. My code looks like this:

`FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();
 prof.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
 prof.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional",  "about:blank");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);`

Comment: @Tudor This code snippets looks fine. I suspect the error is caused by syntax error in another place. Check if you have all the closing brackets.

Comment: I found the problem, the code must be in the main method in order for it to work. The issue now is that my main method contains all functions written in another class. If i initialize in main method, the other class does not have access to "driver" variable. If i initialize in the other class, it shows the errors above. Any ideas on how to make "driver" visible for the other class? (my main class extends the other so i can call all functions from there).

Comment: @Tudor create member `WebDriver driver` and initialize it. You can access it from other class using getter.

Comment: Can you give me an example using code statements on how to declare everything and where please?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers! I did as you said, but driver.getDriver has the following syntax error`"Syntax error on token "getDriver", Identifier expected after this token"`, and inside the class where i have driver variable i get the following error for each driver instance `"Multiple markers at this line
 - The method get(String) is undefined for the type 
  MyDriver
 - Line breakpoint:ReqOrImportCode [line: 20] - 
  page()
 - driver cannot be resolved"`

Comment: @Tudor `driver.getDriver()` is the driver, `driver.getDriver().findElement(...)`

Comment: Don't do `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);`, only `driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);`

Comment: Thanks. Now it works until it gets to the page i need to test, afterwards it gives another error "JavaScript warning: http://gastest.amegt.com/view/js/lib/gas/login.js, line 151: unreachable code after return statement"...

Comment: i did this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(profi), i guess it's ok right?

Comment: @Tudor I don't know where line 151 is (I'm not going to count lines to find it), but the error message is clear: you have code after `return` that can't be reached.

Comment: Yeah, i know you're not going to count the lines:)) the reason i put the error here is that at line 151 there is nothing that has any connection with the login screen page where my program hangs :D so i thought that is a general error message and thought i should ask about it. well, i'll see what i can do then. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Also the only return i have is the one you pointed out earlier, return driver

Comment: @Tudor You can add to the class whatever you need, this is just a basic example.